# RangeV3: why not specialize algorithm for specific containers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, range-v3

The "old" STL does not allow say `std::find` to be specialized to use the member functions for `std::set` or `std::unordered_map`, etc.  It cannot, since the former use iterators, the latter need the containers, and from iterators there are no means to get the containers.  There is even a question about that ([Specializing STL algorithms so they automatically call efficient container member functions when available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573139/specializing-stl-algorithms-so-they-automatically-call-efficient-container-membe)).

Since Range V3 finally moves the focus from iterators to ranges, one could expect that finally `std::find` would be specialized automatically for `std::set`, which in turn makes `std::none_of_equal` (if it were adopted) do what you'd like, etc.

However, reading [its currently implementation](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/algorithm/find.hpp), I see no provision for such a feature.  Why?

Comment: I think it's hard to do this generically, since `find` by default operates on `==` while `set` by default operates on `<`. So even for these defaults, you'd have to require consistency between `<` and `==`. For the more general case, it's just not possible, since the order of `set` and the predicate of `find` might be unrelated. I remember a very similar question, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @dyp if you make this an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20934717/